# web.py & beaker python app. page render issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, web.py, beaker

I have been using web.py recently to try and create an web app, an issue became apparent that we did not have a way of creating multiple sessions, I have tried using beaker (https://github.com/bbangert/beaker) to manage the multiple sessions, but now I have run into an issue of rendering the home page, does anyone have an idea of how to fix this? 
the error we continue to get is

" BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 257, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 248, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 488, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 466, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "app.py", line 92, in GET
    return render.Home()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Home' "

```
    import web
    import datetime
    from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware
    from Models import RegisterModel, LoginModel, Posts

    web.config.debug = False

    urls = (
           '/', 'Home',
            "/register", "Register", 
            "/postreg", "PostRegistration",
            '/login', 'Login',
            '/check-login', "CheckLogin",
            '/logout', 'Logout',
            '/post-activity', 'PostActivity',
            '/profile', 'Profile',
            '/settings', 'Settings',
            '/update-user', 'UpdateSettings',
            '/admin', 'Admin'
            )

    t_globals = {
                 'datestr': web.datestr,
                 'str': str,
                 'datetime': datetime
                 }

    app = web.application(urls, globals())

    session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore("sessions"),initializer={"user":None})
    session_data = session._initializer

    render = web.template.render("Views/Templates", base="MainLayout", globals={"session":session_data, "current_user": session_data["user"]})

    # beaker options are optional.... but it's good to see 
    # where they are called

    session_opts = {
        'session.cookie_expires': True,
        'session.timeout' : 600,
        'session.secure' : True,
    }

    # define webPy app

    # smash it all together and define name for cookie key (sid)
    def session_mw(app):
        return SessionMiddleware(app, config = session_opts, key = "sid")



    # function to check if we are logged in
    def logged(session):
        if 'Login' in session:
            if session['Login']==1:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    # create different renders based on log in privilege
    def create_render(privilege):
        session = web.ctx.environ['beaker.session']
        if logged(session) == True:
            if privilege == 0:
                print("OH BABY")
                render = web.template.render('/Views/Templates/user/', base='/Views/Templates/MainLayout', globals=t_globals)
            elif privilege == 1:
                print("LET ME LOVE YOU")
                render = web.template.render('/Views/Templates/user/', base='/Views/Templates/MainLayout', globals=t_globals)
            elif privilege == 2:
                print("DONT HURT ME")          
                render = web.template.render('/Views/Templates/admin/', base='/Views/Templates/MainLayout', globals=t_globals)
            else:
                print("NOOT NOOT")          
                render = web.template.render('/Views/Templates/viewer', base='/Views/Templates/MainLayout', globals=t_globals)

            render = web.template.render('/Views/Templates/', base='MainLayout', globals=t_globals)
            return render

    class Login:
        def GET(self):
            session = web.ctx.environ['beaker.session']
            if logged(session) == True:
                print("HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH")
                render = create_render(session['privilege'])
                return render.Home()
            else:
                render = create_render(0)
                print("BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH")
                return render.Home()

    # I get user credentials from a database (called in model.get_users) 
        def POST(self):
            session = web.ctx.environ['beaker.session']
            data= web.input()
            name = data['user']
            password = data['password']
            ident = model.get_users(m, name)
            try:
                if password == ident.password.strip():
                    session['Login'] = 1
                    session['privilege'] = ident['privilege']
                    session['user'] = name
                    session.save()
                    render = create_render(session['privilege'])
                    print("HERE")
                    return render.Home()

                else:
                    session.login = 0
                    session.privilege = 0
                    session.user = 'none'
                    render = create_render(session['privilege'])
                    print("NO HERE YO")
                    return render.Login()
            except:
                session['Login'] = 0
                session['privilege'] = 0
                render = create_render(session['privilege'])
                print("BANANA")
                return render.Login()
    # Credits go to bbangert for the middleware code
    class Logout:
        def GET(self):
            session = web.ctx.environ['beaker.session']    
            try:
                render = create_render(0)
                session.invalidate()
                session.delete()
                print("TOPSY TURVY")
                return render.Login()
            except:
                session.invalidate()
                session.delete()
                render = create_render(0)
                print("MESSY RIGHT")
                return render.Login()

    class Home:
        def GET(self):
            session = web.ctx.environ['beaker.session']
            if logged(session) == False:
                raise web.seeother('/login')
            else:
                render = create_render(0)
                return render.Home()

       # '''
        def GET(self):
            data = type('obj', (object,), {'username':'q', 'password':'q'})
            login = LoginModel.LoginModel()
            isValid = login.check_user(data)
            if isValid:
              session_data['user'] = isValid

            post_model = Posts.Posts()
            posts = post_model.get_all_posts()

            return render.Home(posts)
      #  '''

    class Register:
        def GET(self):
          return render.Register()

    class PostRegistration:
        def POST(self):
          print("DOING POST PROCESSING")
          data = web.input()
          reg_model = RegisterModel.RegisterModel()
          reg_model.insert_user(data)
          return data.username

    class CheckLogin:
        def POST(self):
          print("DOING CHECK LOGIN")
          data = web.input()
          login = LoginModel.LoginModel()
          isValid = login.check_user(data)
          if isValid:
            session_data["user"] = isValid
            return isValid
          return "error"

    class PostActivity:
        def POST(self):
          print("DOING POST ACTIVITY")
          data = web.input()
          data.username = session_data['user']['username']
          post_model = Posts.Posts()
          post_model.insert_post(data)    
          return "success"

    class Profile:
        def GET(self):
          return render.Profile()

    class Settings:
        def GET(self):
          return render.Settings()

    class UpdateSettings:
        def POST(self):
          data = web.input()
          data.username = session_data['user']['username']
          update = RegisterModel.RegisterModel()
          update.update_settings(data)
          return "success"

    class Admin:
      def GET(self):
        return render.Admin()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(session_mw)
```

Comment: Did you carry out any kind of debugging? Also try to provide a minimal example.

Comment: `web.py` includes session management & it would appear you have defined `render` way too many times / places. Simplify your example to get to a root cause.